# Returning a byte from /dev/random in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, io, x86

I'm trying to open `/dev/random`, read one byte from it and exit with it as status... in x86 assembly.
This seems to return random numbers, but I'm not sure it does what I think it does.

```
# Where do we get our random numbers from
.data
    random: .ascii "/dev/random\0"

# Program goes here
.text
    .global _start
    _start:

    # Get /dev/random fd
    movl $5, %eax      # sys_open (originally $0 by accident)
    movl $random, %ebx # Filename string
    movl $0, %ecx      # O_RDONLY flag
    int $0x80

    # Read one byte onto stack
    movl %eax, %ebx    # The result of sys_open
    movl $3, %eax      # sys_read
    subl $1, %esp      # Make stack space
    movl %esp, %ecx    # Make stack our buffer
    movl $1, %edx      # size_t bytes? only 1
    int $0x80

    # Exit with a random result
    movl %esp, %ebx    # random result as exit status
    movl $1, %eax      # sys_exit
    int $0x80
```

When I run it through `strace` I get the following back:

```
execve("./random", ["./random"], [/* 44 vars */]) = 0
fstat(0, NULL)                          = 3
close(0)                                = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
write(0, NULL, 1 <unfinished ...>
+++ exited with 12 +++
```

Notice lack of `open()` and `read()`! Also, where did `exit()` go?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question seems to be more about "How to read from /dev/random" than it is about "getting a random number".  Please change the title so that future readers won't be mislead.  [ *If* your purpose is to get a random number quickly, this probably isn't the way to do it.]

Comment: Ok. changed to "Returning a byte from /dev/random in assembly"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Thanks everyone.

[minuteman3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226766/minuteman3) suggested use of `pop`. While it didn't directly solve my issue it led me to another involving use of 32 bit code on a 64 bit machine. Few assembler flags later everything works. Here's the final code for anyone interested:

```
# Where do we get our random numbers from
.code32
.data
    random: .ascii "/dev/random\0"

# Program goes here
.text
    .global _start
    _start:

    # Get our random number
    movl $5, %eax      # sys_open
    movl $random, %ebx # Filename string
    movl $0, %ecx      # O_RDONLY flag
    int $0x80

    # Read one random number
    movl %eax, %ebx    # The result of sys_open
    movl $3, %eax      # sys_read
    pushl $0           # Make space on stack and clear it
    movl %esp, %ecx    # The stack is our buffer
    movl $1, %edx      # size_t bytes?
    int $0x80

    # Exit with a random result
    popl %ebx          # Get the number back
    movl $1, %eax      # sys_exit
    int $0x80
```

compiled with

```
as random.s --32 -W -g -o random.o && ld random.o -o random -melf_i386
```

Comment: interestingly `.code32` instruction makes the code compile fine without the extra flags.. it just "doesn't work" afterwards

Answer (score 1):

To make a system call, you have to follow the kernel's system call API. Since I don't know what it is, I always [look it up online](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html). Then I find that `sys_open` should look like this:

```
mov $5, %eax          ;; syscall number "open"
mov $random, %ebx     ;; arg 1: char * filename
mov $0, %ecx          ;; arg 2: int flags
int $0x80
```

Comment: Yes, Sorry that's an accident. I was aware of that, edited the question code.

Answer (score 0):

In the reference I have the edx register needs the file open mode mask.

Additionally you never restore sp after adding 1.

I would also subtract/add 4 not 1.  Linux may not do well with unaligned esp values.

Also it looks like you are returning the low byte of esp rather than the memory at esp. Put the %esp in the movl instruction in parens.

Comment: This is AT&T syntax, so I think it's parenthesis. Are you sure? Doing so seems to crash the program, I can't access that memory.

Comment: Right. You do need to  get the value from memory. The crash is probably because you never restore the stack pointer. Also pls see added note on setting edx reg.

Comment: What's the flags value? I'm not certain on it though.. According to kernel source, the last argument is "mode for the new file if O_CREAT is set, else ignored". I have only O_RDONLY set, so it shouldn't matter, and indeed seems to make no difference.

Comment: I was looking at the file open macro on Page 5 of this http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/images/e/e3/CSC231_File_IO_In_Assembly.pdf  .  It uses `mov edx, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IXUSR`  But I agree other documents imply the mode is used only for file creation.